# hide update and cancel button after click on updtae button

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax

we are using this code for updating the price .

once we click on "update" button its displaying as like in image .

what we need is once we click on "update" buttton, than " Update" and "cancel" button should hide.

for "cancel" button, its working fine. once we click on "cancel" buttton, than " Update" and "cancel" button is hiding[image].

```
<span class="label pro_status">
    <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>

        <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span>
    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>


    <!-- aki 2 -->
    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" 
src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
        </span>  
    <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>
    <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
                <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
                                                        </button>
    <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
                                                        </button>                                                       
                                                    </span>
```

**script**

```
<script>
function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
        {
            var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';

            $wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($price);
            hideReset(product_id);


    </script>
```

Comment: $wk_jq(updateButton).show(); change this to $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();

Comment: update button is  hiding, but cancel button is visible

Comment: $wk_jq(resetButton).show(); to $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();

Comment: its not working......

Comment: i need something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/g1v9x1bt/

Comment: var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id; change this to var resetButton = "#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

Comment: post ur comment as answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make these three changes..

```
$wk_jq(updateButton).show(); change this to $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();



var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id; change this to var resetButton = "#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;



$wk_jq(resetButton).show(); to $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
```